# Horizontal UIScrollView and hundreds of thumbnail images in iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I need to create a horizontal UIScrollView which to hold hundreds of thumbnail images, just like a slide of thumbnails.

For example, there will be 10 thumbnails showing in a single screen, each of them are horizontally adjacent to each other.

My problem is that I don't know how to make a horizontal UIScrollView to hold the multiple thumbnails which showing at the same time ?

A sample photo is as below. See the bottom part of the screen.

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: consider as contentSize(tumbnileImagescount*width,tumbnileImage).and set pagingEnabled property as Yes for horizontal scroll.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can add all the thumbnails programatically to your scrollview and use the setContentSize method of UIScrollView. you have to pass 2 values in contentOffset. 1 for width and 1 for height. Please follow [link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Scrolling/Introduction/Intro.html) to explore more on this. If you need further help please leave a comment.

Hope it helps.

Please consider Following example.

```
- (void)setupHorizontalScrollView
{
scrollView.delegate = self;

[self.scrollView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
[scrollView setCanCancelContentTouches:NO];

scrollView.indicatorStyle = UIScrollViewIndicatorStyleWhite;
scrollView.clipsToBounds = NO;
scrollView.scrollEnabled = YES;
scrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;

NSUInteger nimages = 0;
NSInteger tot=0;
CGFloat cx = 0;
for (; ; nimages++) {
    NSString *imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"image%d.jpg", (nimages + 1)];
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];
    if (tot==15) {
        break;
    }
    if (4==nimages) {
        nimages=0;
    }

    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];

    CGRect rect = imageView.frame;
    rect.size.height = 40;
    rect.size.width = 40;
    rect.origin.x = cx;
    rect.origin.y = 0;

    imageView.frame = rect;

    [scrollView addSubview:imageView];
    [imageView release];

    cx += imageView.frame.size.width+5;
    tot++;
}

self.pageControl.numberOfPages = nimages;
[scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(cx, [scrollView bounds].size.height)];
}
```

---

Comment: Thank you. Does UIScrollView allow multiple small thumbnails to show in a single screen. I need a slider of thumbnails. Thanks again.

Comment: @user403015 I have edited answer and posted code of horizontal scrolling gallery. It is with certain fixes which you can make dynamic according to your requirement. In this I have consider that in my program I have 5 images and want to added those by repeating for 3 times. so tot=15 and nimages==4. I have tested above code with IOS 4.0 and it is working. If you need more clarification please do leave comment. If this resolves your program Accept the answer or upvote. Thanks.

Comment: Jennis, you are very kind. Will it consume a lot of memory as I need to load 100+ thumbnails ? Or does it just load the thumbnails which are visible ?

Comment: @user403015 Yeah I have looked the screenshot. How do you create your UIScrollView ? Can you post some of your code ?

Comment: Hi, Jennis, the image is not mine. Would you please answer my questions above when you have spare time.

Comment: @user403015 I believe that will not consume memory as you can see that after adding UIImageView to scrollview we are releasing the allocated memory. But loading time depends on the images count and size again. And further if you want to load UIScrollView like lazy loading i.e. when you scroll if not loaded image it will be loaded that is also possible but its different approach. Apply this code and see if it suits you or you need to take lazy loading approach.

Comment: what is self.pageControl?

Comment: UIPageControl if you wish to display number of pages.

Answer (score 4):

Check out bjhomer's [HSImageSidebarView](https://github.com/bjhomer/HSImageSidebarView) project. It lets you load a scrollview horizontally or vertically and load in the images. Super easy to implement.

Answer (score 4):

I suggest you to look at [nimbus](http://latest.docs.nimbuskit.info/group___nimbus_overview.html)

Answer (score 2):

First of all, at `storyboard` drag and drop the scroll view and make the outlet of `scrollview` named `scrollView`. Two array one is `mutable` and one is `immutable`.

```
@property(nonatomic,strong)IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollView;
@property(nonatomic,strong)NSMutableArray *images;
@property(nonatomic,strong)NSArray *imagesName;
```

The `immutable` array only store the images which we want to show on the scroll view.Make sure `UIscrollview` delegate is defined.
In `viewcontoller.m` file in `didload` function do following code:

```
imagesName = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"centipede.jpg",@"ladybug.jpg",@"potatoBug.jpg",@"wolfSpider.jpg",          @"ladybug.jpg",@"potatoBug.jpg",@"centipede.jpg",@"wolfSpider.jpg",nil];

// mutable array used to show the images on scrollview dynamic becaus after one
// image when scroll other will come
images = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
scrollView.delegate = self;
scrollView.scrollEnabled = YES;
int scrollWidth = 120;
scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(scrollWidth,80);

int xOffset = 0;

//the loop go till all images will load  
for(int index=0; index < [imagesName count]; index++)
{            
    UIImageView *img = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
    // make the imageview object because in scrollview we need image
    img.frame = CGRectMake(5+xOffset, 0, 160, 110);
    // the offset represent the values, used so that topleft for each image will
    // change with(5+xOffset, 0)and the bottomright(160, 110) 
    NSLog(@"image: %@",[imagesName objectAtIndex:index]);
    img.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[imagesName objectAtIndex:index]];
    // The image will put on the img object
    [images insertObject:img atIndex:index];
    // Put the img object at the images array which is mutable array
    scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(scrollWidth+xOffset,110);
    //scroll view size show after 125 width the scroll view enabled
    [scrollView addSubview:[images objectAtIndex:index]];
    // set images on scroll view      
    xOffset += 170;
}
```

Comment: i have tried this but the scroll is not working horizontally . do you know what could be the problem ? or do you have any other updated code regarding this ? or you have any new methodology or scenario to implement like this ? please guide me through this .

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate content size width of the scrollview as width = number of images * size of each image. Then set contentSize of the scrollview to this width and the height that you want `(scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(width, height))`