# Empty Nsmutable Array Iphone

Tags: iphone, uitableview, nsmutablearray

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Images in Uiscroll cell populated by mysql database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10859728/images-in-uiscroll-cell-populated-by-mysql-database)

```
-(void)getItems 
{
    NSString *root = URL

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/phpfile", root]];

    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) 
    {
        [self.object removeAllObjects];

        id results = [JSON valueForKeyPath:@"ids"];

        [results enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) 
        {
            [self.object addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[obj valueForKey:@"item1"]]];
            [self.object2 addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[obj valueForKey:@"item2"]]];


-(void)DidLoad
{
    //initializing arrays to hold data

    //Initiate arrays that hold data
    object1 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    object2 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [getItems];
    //Why do I get empty arrays here e.g object 1 and 2 are returning empty ?
```

Comment: Please make your question more clear when posting here.

Comment: @MichaelDautermann, it is the same code, different questions. I posted it twice because I got partial answer.. thank you

Comment: @ShaggyFrog.. thank you for your quick response.. these mutable arrays objec1, and object2 have objects (URL string with object) object 1 has names of the photos and object 2 has the url of the photos. I wanted to get these details e.g names of the photos. But NSMutable array here is returning empty.. is this clear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming this is your question:

```
//Why do I get empty arrays here e.g object 1 and 2 are returning empty ?
```

This code:

```
//Initiate arrays that hold data
object1 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
object2 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

Is creating new arrays dynamically on the heap. They are naturally empty because they were just brought into existence.

This line:

```
[getItems];
```

I think you are trying to call the `getItems` method you posted above, but you are not referencing an object in the method call. You want:

```
[self getItems];
```

And even then, you still have a problem; assuming the `get` part of the name is supposed to be getting something (items), you are not returning anything from the method (which is marked with a `void` return type).