# How to display all doucment directory images in thumbnail view in iphone

Tags: iphone

I am new to iphone programming. I have stored some images inside the document directory image folder, but now I want to display all those images in thumbnail view not in tableview.How do I this? Can anyone help, please?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here is MY logic Try See how can you achieve this, Her in below code You just need to manage the calling of code accordingly your requirement.

**NOte**. This is not any complied code this is just My Logic....! for using it you have convert it into runnable code.

```
//here You just call below method for setting the Image 
-(void)checkForOldFilesInDocumentDirectory{

NSFileManager *fileManager=[NSFileManager defaultManager];

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *folderPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"MyIMages"];
//plkease make sure you have only images in that folder.
NSArray *folders   = [fileManager contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:folderPath error:nil];

for(NSString *fileName in folders)
{
   NSString *srcPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForAuxiliaryExecutable:@"fileName"];//path of Image

    //Here you can Pass These Image Form Give Method

    [self getImagesFromDOc:srcPath];
 }
```

}

**EDIT: here below Method Just CReate The `UIImageView` And set The Image Present in DOcument directory over The `UIImageView`.
I am giving the Basic Approach ,Here You need to create Some  UIImageView set image to that UIIMageView And Now You need To add These created `UIImageView` As `SubView` Over The Controller's View.You need TO call this process as many times as number of images present in Document directory.**

```
 - (void)getImagesFromDOc:(NSString*)path
 {
 //Now You have The Path Image
 //Here From You  need to0 create an ImageView, below is just a basic knowledge demo.
 UIImage* finalImage =  [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
 UIImageView * imageView =[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(xOrigin, yOrigin, 30, 30)];
 [imageView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];
 [imageView  setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
 [imageView setImage:finalImage];
 [finalImage release];
 [self.view addSubview:imageView];//Here Add tha ImageView Over SOme current View

 }
```

I hope it may helpful to you.

Comment: hi where i have to write this code inside the button

Comment: @user1788095 you can place at same ViewController where you want to show your Thumbnail Images.But please firstly try to get basic idea behind that code.You need to change the `getImagesFromDOc` method. little bit according to your view .

Comment: ya i change it iam not getting.showing some Exception

Comment: @user1788095 WHAT EXCEPTION put that error log here ... also your code here well see this is link for creating the Thumbnail View http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5973883/horizontal-uiscrollview-and-hundreds-of-thumbnail-images-in-ios.here you just need to call that method which retrive the image from The Document Directory

Comment: 2012-11-17 17:34:43.109 customalbum[902:207] -[UIRoundedRectButton pathExtension]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8d99020
Current language:  auto; currently objective-c

Comment: This Expection is showing and i want to display images like a photo gallery

Comment: - (void)getImagesFromDOc:(NSString*)path

Comment: instead of this i write like this -(IBAction)get:(NSString*)path;is it correct

Comment: @user1788095 hey look, here i had given the idea reagrading how can you obtain the images from The Document director and how you can use that image.that was just the idea. really i  wanted to help you but you know i can't help you just through this way.... so we need to go over the chat network.

Comment: xOrigin, yOrigin these both are showing error

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19677/discussion-between-user1788095-and-ios-deveoper)

Comment: @user1788095 can wait for a while actually i have some office work need to finish first..!!!

Comment: k k thank u.for giving k  i will w8