# Design Shopping Cart for my application

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad

[image: I am developing a shopping application for iPad and I want to add a shopping cart into it just like this image.]

I am developing a shopping application for iPad and I want to add a shopping cart into it just like this image and I also want to add the quantity in the right side of the corner (not shown in image).

I have made the design and also loaded the views as well. but I don't know how to change different image in each view and set different text in all different labels. How do I remove a particular view after clicking on the cancel button?

```
CGFloat x = 0.0;
for (int k=0; k<=15; k++)
{

    NSArray *sub = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomView" owner:self options:nil];
    UIView *tmp = [sub objectAtIndex:0];

    tmp.frame = CGRectMake(x, 0, 60, 50);

    [_scrollView addSubview:tmp];


    x = x + 60;
}
```

Comment: Please [check this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5973883/horizontal-uiscrollview-and-hundreds-of-thumbnail-images-in-ios/5973926#5973926), some what similar to what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has worked for me

```
 CGFloat x = 0.0;
 NSMutableArray * cartArr = [CartDetails getAllProducts];
 for (int k=0; k< [cartArr count]; k++)
 {
   //Add custom view

    UIView * tmpV = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, 0, 60, 50)];
    tmpV.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    // Add imageview to custom view

    UIImageView *tmpImg = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 10, 50, 40)];
    [tmpImg setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"cancel.jpeg"]];
    [tmpV addSubview:tmpImg];

    // Add label to custom view

    UILabel *tmplabel =[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 0, 15, 15)];
    tmplabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    tmplabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",k];
    tmplabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [tmpV addSubview:tmplabel];

    // Add button to custom view

    UIButton * tmpBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [tmpBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(clearCart:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    tmpBtn.frame = CGRectMake(45, 0, 15, 15);
    [tmpBtn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"CloseButton.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [tmpV addSubview:tmpBtn];

   // Add customview to Scroollview

    [_scrollView addSubview:tmpV];

    x = x + 60;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
//make custom circle UILable and put on Image. solve same issue




  UILabel *lbl_cart_count = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(302,6, 22, 22)];
    lbl_cart_count.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    lbl_cart_count.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    lbl_cart_count.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",Temp_card_count];
    lbl_cart_count.layer.borderColor = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;
    lbl_cart_count.layer.borderWidth = 0;
    lbl_cart_count.layer.cornerRadius = 11;
    lbl_cart_count.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:247.0/255.0 green:45.0/255.0 blue:143.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
    lbl_cart_count.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"ArialMT" size:11];
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar lbl_cart_count];
    [lbl_cart_count release];

  [view addSubview:lbl_cart_count];
```

Answer (score 1):

Given you have a reference to the cancel button the user tapped on, and that the cancel button is a subView of the View that contains the Image (Shopping Cart Item, perhaps) (as seen from the image)

Try the following on button click event:

```
[cartItemView removeFromSuperview];

//Your code to realign the items after the removed cart item should follow.
```

So if the user removes the second item (as you have highlighted in your image), you'll have to update the X coordinate of items at indices 2,3,4 and so on (given 0 is the first item). Animating this would be even better.

Comment: what about setting different images??

Comment: If you're targeting iOS 6 and above, I'd recommend you use a UICollectionView with a UICollectionViewFlowLayout instead of a UIScrollView. That way, in the datasource delegate methods, you can set the appropriate images when the collectionView:cellForIndexPath: method

If you wish to keep your current implementation, do something similar to how you're setting the View's frame in your code.

Answer (score 0):

From your requirements, it seems that you'll better be served using a horizontal `UITableView`. You can easily add and remove objects from its data source and simply call `reloadData`.